# How can I support a flexing exterior threshold?

Tags: doors, patio, door-frame, threshold

I've installed a new patio door which has wider threshold and now it bends a little when I step on it since it has no support underneath. Any ideas hot to cover that area and add support so it looks professionally done?

[image]

Comment: What's the plan for finishing the wood door trim?

Comment: wood trim is gonna be the color of siding - white.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it only overhangs 3/4".

Add a 1x3 or 1x4 trim board made of PVC.

Construction adhesive and a few evenly space tapcon screws should do it. Then caulk any seams with polyurethane caulk.

Comment: That's a good idea, though I might consider a piece of composite deck board instead—may be easier to find in a gray color that wouldn't contrast as much with the concrete.